# prevent jumping of affixed element when scrolled

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap's affix plugin [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lLBLojGt3nbMm2FyFED4?p=preview)
HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
   ...
    <style>
      h1 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: green;
        margin: 0;
        top: 10px;
      }

      h1.affix {
        top: 8px;
      }

      body {
        padding: 10px;
        height: 5000px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="10">yo!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Whenever I scroll down for a considerable distance (using scroll on the right, not the mouse scroll), the div jumps. How can I prevent that? Apperantly the problem is div scrolls up beyond the screen, then it's applied a fixed position and it moves down causing it to jump. I tried using transition to make it jump smoother, but for some reason it didn't work.

```
h1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    margin: 0;
    transition-property: top;
    transition-duration: 3s;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use `affix` class

```
 <h1 class="affix">yo!</h1>
```

Now it will not jump !

Comment: In this way it won't jump because it becomes fixed rightaway, where my code has `h1` positioned statically.

Comment: May i know why your `h1` positioned statically.

Comment: Because I want it to move with content when scrolling and only stick to the top when it reaches the top. The example is not 100% representative in the way that it already has `h1` at the top, but in production it's not going to be that way